# High DPC latency NDIS, what should I do?

Tags: windows, drivers, performance, network-adapter, latency

Laptop:
Gigabyte P34k Windows 10, connected to the internet using ethernet port:

When the latency spikes the laptops speakers crackle.

Results are as followed:

[image: LatencyMon Main Results]

[image: Stats and Driver Report]

Any advice on fixing the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: update the network card drivers and all network related software

Comment: Can't everything is up to date. If you mean revert back to an old drive I've tried that.

Comment: which windows version do you use?

Comment: Windows 10, 64-bit operating system, x64. That's all I know, as windows was pre-installed on the laptop when bought.

Comment: have you made the update to version 1607? if not, try this update

Comment: Turns out HitmanPro.Alert (HPA) was to blame. Therefore, uninstalling HPA fixed the latency issue.

Comment: ok, post you finding as answer